# Getting NullPointerException while calling nested method of Service class using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am writing JUnit test cases for my Service classes.
I have created dummy data to understand my scenario.

```
@Service
MainClass {
    @Autowired
    C c;
    public void someServiceMethod(){
        ResultClass someResult = c.getResult(string,string, int, int, List<String>,boolean);
    }
}

@Service
public class C {
    @Autowired
    SomeRepository someRepository;
    public ResultClass getResult(string,string, int, int, List<String>,boolean){
        ABC returnSomeClassObject = someRepository.getSomeData(String,int,int);
    }
}

@Test
MainClassTest {
    @MockBean
    SomeRepository someRepository;
    when(someRepository.getSomeData(anyString(),anyInt(),anyInt())).thenReturn(SomeRepository);

    //calling MainClass method
    MainClass.someServiceMethod();
}
```

Class C's getSomeData() method returning ABC class object which is NULL and latter setting into another same class type object.
After setting value I am getting NULLPointerException as ABC is NULL.
Anybody have any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: I admit I am not really familiar with this syntax for using Mockito, but it looks to me like your `getSomeData` method returns a `ResultClass`, but when you stub it you are returning a `SomeRepository` object. Try creating a `ResultClass` and return that instead.

Comment: What is your intention ? Do you want to only mock the result of  someRepository 's getSomeData()  and test MainClass 's someServiceMethod() ?

Comment: @KenChan Oh yeah that's a good point. If OP was intending to test `someServiceMethod` then OP should be stubbing `getResult` not `getSomeData`. A little more info is needed I think.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning expected object while writing mock statement

```
    @Service
public class C {
    @Autowired
    SomeRepository someRepository;
    public ResultClass getResult(string,string, int, int, List<String>,boolean){
        ABC returnSomeClassObject = someRepository.getSomeData(String,int,int);

        //Your return type should be ResultClass 
        // Where your return statement
        // What is ABC?
    }
}

@Test
MainClassTest {
    @MockBean
    SomeRepository someRepository;
    when(someRepository.getSomeData(anyString(),anyInt(),anyInt())).thenReturn(SomeRepository);
    // Why are you returning SomeRepository, This Should return object of ABC

@MockBean 
ABC mockResultClass
when(someRepository.getSomeData(anyString(),anyInt(),anyInt())).thenReturn(mockResultClass);

    //calling MainClass method
    MainClass.someServiceMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `MainClass.someServiceMethod()` which in turn calls getResult of class C. You should be mocking class C and using when-thenReturn on `getResult()` of C class if your intention is to test `someServiceMethod()` of `Main` class. `Autowired` will not work here since this is a Unit test and hence the instance of C c in Main class will be null. 
Something like below:

```
@MockBean
C c;
when(c.getResult(anyString(), anyString(),anyInt(),anyInt(), any(List.class), anyBoolean()).thenReturn(someResult);

c.getResult(string,string, int, int, List<String>,boolean);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, we need to be clear on what exactly you are unit testing. If you are trying to unit test `someServiceMethod` inside of `MainClass`, then that means you should NOT be also testing the functionality of `someRepository`. The idea is that each unit test should only be testing just that, a unit of code. So, to do that we need to use stubs as stand-ins for what would actually happen when you call methods owned by other classes. Then, we would write a differrent unit test just for `someRepository.getSomeData()` to confirm that it is also working as intended. In this manner, when get an error later down the line we will know exactly where we are encountering an issue.

Another issue I see is there is an apparent mismatch of return types for `getResult()` in `C`. The method says it returns a `ResultClass`, but when you call `getSomeData` you are expecting an `ABC` object. Either you left out the details where you convert the object back to a `ResultClass`, or that is a mistake. I'm going to assume the former unless you say otherwise.

With that in mind, let's write our test. Here's how I would write the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MainClassTest {

    @Mock
    C c;

    @InjectMocks
    MainClass mainClass;

    @Test
    public void testSomeServiceMethod {

        ResultClass resultClass = new ResultClass(); //relevant constructor details here, mockbean, etc. you get the idea

        //set any desired data for resultClass here

        Mockito.when(c.getResult(anyString(), anyString(), 
            anyInt(), anyInt(), any(List.class), anyBoolean()))
            .thenReturn(resultClass);

        ResultClass newResult = mainClass.someServiceMethod();

        //relevant test assertions here
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are creating a `ResultClass` in the test, and telling Mockito to return that when `getResult` is called instead of what you would normally expect it to return. While the functionality may seem limited now, this is preferred as we only testing the `MainClass` and not the rest of our method calls.

In addition to this, we can (and should) write tests for `getResult` in `C`, and `getSomeData` in `SomeRepository`. I will leave it to you to write those tests.

EDIT: accidentally posted a bit early, fixing now.